# send mail not working after moving to AWS

Tags: php, smtp, amazon-ses

After I transferred hosts from Hostgator to AWS Ubuntu, sending mail no longer works. For example, when someone registers, it should send an automated email to that user. I am using X-Mailer PHP. What is causing the problem? Did I miss installing something on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup mail on the server for it to work, it doesn't just work on it's own. HostGator manages the server for you, so they set it up. On Amazon, you are going to have to set it up yourself.

Comment: Ohhh thanks so much! How do I set it up?

Comment: There are plenty of good tutorials out there, a quick Google search will give you a proper answer.

Comment: Take a look at sending emails using SES smtp servers.